# How to scan open port of client machine using local IP address in C# in MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, port

I am developing a web application in MVC. When user log in to website I am getting local IP address of user. But now what I want to do is scan list of open ports of client local machine.

Is there any way to implement this in JavaScript or jQuery or C# in MVC?

Comment: What would you try doing first? What documentation, tutorial or example did you consult? Where do you get stuck? What does the relevant part of your code look like, if there is any?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void btnPing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int intCount = 0;
            int maxip = 0;
            richTmp.Clear();
            string strIP = null;
            string machineName = string.Empty;
            List<string> strListIp = new List<string>();
            List<string> txtBuffrFile = new List<string>();
            BufferdIp = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
            {
               System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping p = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
               lstDetails.Items.Add("System Found: " + maxip);
               System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply rep = p.Send("192.168.1." + i,500);
                if (rep.Status == System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    intCount++;
                    lstDetails.Items.Clear();
                    lstDetails.Items.Add("Loading...Total(" + maxip+")");
                    strIP = rep.Address.ToString();
                    machineName = GetMachineNameFromIPAddress(strIP);
                   if (machineName == string.Empty || machineName == null)
                    {
                        strListIp.Add(strIP + ":-" + "Offline");
                        BufferdIp.Add("0");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strListIp.Add(strIP + ":-" + machineName+"(Online)");
                        BufferdIp.Add(strIP);
                        txtBuffrFile.Add(strIP);
                        maxip++;
                    }
                }

            }
            lstDetails.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var IDAddres in strListIp)
            {
                lstDetails.Items.Add(IDAddres);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i != txtBuffrFile.Count;i++ )
            {
                richTmp.Text += txtBuffrFile.ElementAt(i) + "\n";
            }
            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Save This Search", "Save Dialog", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == (DialogResult.Yes))
            {
                if(File.Exists (path))
                File.Delete(path);
                FileStream stream = File.Create(path);
                stream.Close();
                File.WriteAllText(path, richTmp.Text, Encoding.UTF8);

            }
            btnConnct.Enabled = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I use this to ping in my LAN area but problem is this works only when you know IP pattern and Range :(